The shorter version
The answer is a single word.

1 A reality show of people being watched by an older sibling
2 How heavy/light a person is
3 International battle
4 An American film company founded by four brothers
     
            
           In a "secret alphabet"
      
    2  2  2  2  2  2  4  2  4  4  2  1  4
    3  2  2  1  4  2  2  3  1  2  4  4  2
    3  3  3  2  3  1  3  3  2  3  2  2  2
      


The clue answers are:

 1. Big Brother (BB)
 2. Body Weight (BW)
 3. World War (WW)
 4. Warner Brothers (WB)

These can be

 reinterpreted as 'black' and 'white'. This turns each column of 3 numbers into a 2x3 grid. Reading this grid as Braille spells the answer, ABBREVIATIONS.


 Braille:  


Correct, well done! Just added an image so it becomes easier to follow.
